# Take error on wlst console when work with statements or loops

Tags: python, oracle, weblogic, wlst

Not able to make loop and statement after it.

Example:

```
wls:/ADMIN_server/serverConfig> serverRuntime()
Location changed to serverRuntime tree. This is a read-only tree with ServerRuntimeMBean as the root.
For more help, use help(serverRuntime)

wls:/ADMIN_server/serverRuntime> dsMBeans = cmo.getJDBCServiceRuntime().getJDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBeans()
wls:/ADMIN_server/serverRuntime> ds_name = "ADMIN_DB"
wls:/ADMIN_server/serverRuntime> for ds in dsMBeans:
...
Traceback (innermost last):
  (no code object) at line 0
  File "<console>", line 2
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not sure is it need to import something before that options like and for that reason not able to make loop with statement:

```
import time
import sys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to import anything specific to have access to the looping mechanism in WLST. For instance, try the following:

```
slist=range(1,4)
for i in slist: print 'i = ' + str(i);
```

The result should be:

```
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
```

The syntax of your statements after the for loop are probably causing a problem in your python script OR if you are manually typing the commands in, you need to make sure you put a space after `...` for it to interpret the next line like:

```
wls:/offline> j = 0
wls:/offline> while j<4:
... print 'j = ' + str(j)
... j = j + 1
...
jms 0
jms 1
jms 2
jms 3
```

Notice it is very important to type in a space character after `...` or you will have the invalid syntax error.

Comment: The problem was that not set correctly environment settings. I fix it when load `source /home/BEA/wlserver_10.3/server/bin/setWLSEnv.sh`. Tip with the statement also work.